# resolving java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean

Tags: java, sql, database, ms-access, jtable

I'm still new in programming. Currently, I have a program that checks the attendance of an employee. The employee id & names are retrieved from a database. The daily attendance of an employee is saved in an attendance table in the database, with fields having only an ID,empID,dateAttended,"present","overtime". Now, I want to retrieve all the values from the attendance table. At first, I can retrieve the values fine but after I added the "a.dateAttended" and "a.Present", I get this Exception. Any suggestions on how i can resolve this?

```
private void attendanceView(){
    try{
        String query ="SELECT e.ID,e.firstName,e.lastName,e.position,a.dateAttended,a.Present FROM employees e INNER JOIN attendance a ON e.ID=a.empID";
        Object[][] result = connectToDB(query);

        attendanceTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            result, new String [] {"Employee ID","First Name","Last Name", "Position", "Date", "Present"}
        ) 
        {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Boolean.class
            };
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, false, false, false, false, true
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });   
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
}
```

Comment: Quit posting multiple questions on the same topic. You asked (and then deleted) this same question earlier. Reposting will NOT get better help and people will not know what has already been suggested in the other posting and may waste time repeating the suggestion. Your question still doesn't state what the problem is. Is the problem the SQL, the building of the table, something else?

Comment: Just run a querry to get all your information

Comment: @camickr there's no suggestion made earlier, so I reposted it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @phil652 how can I add the where clause properly? "SELECT e.ID,e.firstName,e.lastName,e.position,a.dateAttended FROM employees e INNER JOIN Attendance a ON a.empID =e.ID WHERE a.dateAttended = (month of the system date)";

Comment: What is your question exacly? This querry does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this, in the comments,

```
SELECT e.ID,e.firstName,e.lastName,e.position,a.dateAttended 
FROM employees e INNER JOIN Attendance a ON a.empID =e.ID 
WHERE a.dateAttended = (month of the system date)
```

A google search on ms access date functions led me to now(), which returns the current date and time, and month(), which returns the month number.  That means you can do this:

```
SELECT e.ID,e.firstName,e.lastName,e.position,a.dateAttended 
FROM employees e INNER JOIN Attendance a ON a.empID =e.ID 
WHERE month(a.dateAttended) = month(now())
```

However, there are better ways to do this.  Using functions in the where clause like that slows down production.  Plus, this is only good for the current month.  I suggest that you use your java code to generate two date variables.  The first one is the first day of the month you want to search and the other one is the first day of the following month.  Then your where clause would be this

```
where a.dateAttended >= the first variable
and a.datAttended < the other variable
```

Using query parameters would improve it even more, if access supports those.  I don't use it so I don't know.